# Вёрстка, подскажите по PSD

Tags: html, вёрстка, psd

Скинули тестовое задание, заверстать псдешку, не могу понять, что хотят от секций, если есть у кого минута времени, объясните пожалуйста.
мои версии
1) хотя чтоб все элементы перелистывались в хедере псд
2) верстать как обычный вертикальный макет, где все элементы по порядку.

[ссылка на PSD](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FgVtI1rI6zHQatCdhtJxONI29x77eK91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужен какой-нибудь постраничный слайдер (например, fullPage.js). Дальше верстаешь просто слайды (по сути второй вариант, но слайдер всё соберёт), 1 слайд - одна секция.

Comment: спасибо Владимир!